# Visual Studio 2015 opens file from inetpub instead of local file while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I've got a problem while attempting to debug my ASP.NET MVC site in Visual Studio 2015.  Don't think it matters, but it's a Sitecore MVC site.

I deploy locally to an IIS 10 website. I place a breakpoint on my cshtml view.  I attach to the w3wp.exe process.  When the proper page loads in the browser, Visual Studio opens up another tab that contains my view, but the path to it uses the `'inetpub'` path.  So instead of opening `'\vs\code\mysite\views\myview.cshtml'`, it opens `'\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\views\myview.cshtml.'`  While both tabs are open, I can see that my breakpoint is only on the `inetpub` version and attempting to set a breakpoint on the 'local code' version results in Visual Studio switching to the inetpub version. (doesn't allow me to set a breakpoint on the local code version)

So, the breakpoint is still hit, but I don't have intellisense in my immediate window.  After stopping debugging, I'm left with two tabs with the same view and have to figure out which one to modify before deploying again.  Larger issue is that I don't have intellisense, but I suspect this is due to this issue of opening the wrong file.  Note: I do have intellisense during the same debugging session for another library project that is further down the execution path.

Feels like a VS configuration issue, but I have been unsuccessful in locating what the issue might be.  Anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Think I can narrow down this issue at bit more now after some additional research.  When the code first attaches, it thinks the breakpoint won't be hit and says `The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  A copy of myview.cshtml was found in App.Web...(server-side symbols)`  So looks like it's having trouble finding the right PDB.  I'm leaving the question open, but have a whole new slew of things to check.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and then a republish from VS?

Comment: Thanks @jammykam, yes, I've tried that. :/  Something is messy with the loading of the symbols.

Comment: My other suggestion would be to delete your custom dlls and views from your inetpub folder and try another republish. Either of these methods usually resolve the issue for me.